# Swift 2.2 - NSTimer with optional completion-handler selector

Tags: swift2, nstimer, option-type, completionhandler

I am trying to call a function with optional `CompletionHandler` parameter from a timer. Below is my code snippet:

```
typealias CompletionHandler = () -> Void

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.check(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

    func check(completion: CompletionHandler?) {
        print("userinfo1")
    }

}
```

When the timer is triggered after `1.0` second, my app is dead with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` and the pointer points to `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate` in `AppDelegate`.

Can you show me how I can call `check` function with such parameter? (If `completion` is just an Int,  the timer did work!)

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can create a timer like this:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(connectionTimeoutExpired(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

func connectionTimeoutExpired(sender: NSTimer) {
        print("Connection Timeout Expired")
        connectionTimer?.invalidate()
        connectionTimer = nil
    }
```

Comment: Reason I want to call `check` (not `check1` with `sender` as `NSTimer`) is I already had `check` and I want to reuse it.